# Right Rails way to write RPSECs to test URL routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, specifications

I have a app with this kind of setup:

```
User (id)
Room (id, private (boolean)
RoomMember(user_id, room_id, banned (boolean)
```

These are the use cases I want to write tests for:

1. If the room is not private the user can join and is redirect to the right url
2. If the room is private, the user is redirect to the Enter Password Page
3. If the user has been banned, they are redirect to '/'

What's the right rails rspec way to test these user stories?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be possible (with your modification):

```
describe "User Permissions" do

  it "should allow users to join public rooms" do
    user = User.new
    room = Room.new( private: false )

    get "[your_action]"
    response.should render_template( "path/to/room/show/template" )
  end

  it "should honor privacy" do
    user = User.new
    room = Room.new( private: true )

    get "[your_action]"
    response.should redirect_to( action: '[enter_password_action]' )
  end

  it "shouldn't allow banned users to enter rooms" do
    user = User.new( banned: true )
    room = Room.new

    get "[your_action]"
    response.should redirect_to( "/" )
  end

end
```

More on writing Rspec Rails Controller tests can be found [here](http://rspec.info/rails/writing/controllers.html).

Comment: Thanks, so this is considered a controller test, not a route test?

Comment: Also, will this take CanCan into consideration for ability.rb permissions?

Comment: Also, given that a User Permissions model does not exist which file should this live in?

Comment: First: I'm learning Rails myself, so this is all what I think to be the case, but you may want to confirm elsewhere. This is technically considered a functional test (which is the folder in which this should use). I'm not completely familiar with CanCan, but you can find information regarding testing it [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities). They very well may suggest tests different than what I suggested, and in this case, it would be must safer to favor their suggestions over mine :).